# How to remove element from Generic Array

Tags: c#, arrays, generics

I have  generic array [] with some things, lets say the objects of class Student, and I need a method(void) that takes as the argument the object of class Student and removes it from generic array.
Yeah I need to use Exactly Array, not a List.

I've tried to use LinQ but that doesn't work.
Here is some code:

```
public class ClassDepartment<T> : IDepartment <T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Supervisor { get; set; }
    public void EnrollStudent(T student)
    {
        T[] aboba = new T[1] {student};
        list = list.Concat(aboba).ToArray();
    }
    public void DeleteStudent(T student)
    {
        // I NEED CODE HERE

    }
    public T[] list {get; set;} = new T[0];
}
```

And here it is the Main void:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Physical first = new Physical()
    {
        Fio = "Darya Griko",
        SportDiscipline = "Hokkei"
    };
    Physical second = new Physical()
    {
        Fio = "David Darbinyan",
        SportDiscipline = "Football"
    };
    Physical third = new Physical()
    {
        Fio = "Egor Zhukov",
        SportDiscipline = "Volleyboll"
    };
    ClassDepartment<Physical> aboba = new ClassDepartment<Physical>()
    {
        Name = "Physical",
        Supervisor = "David Darbinyan"
    };
    aboba.EnrollStudent(first);
    aboba.EnrollStudent(second);
    aboba.EnrollStudent(third);
    aboba.DeleteStudent(second);

}
```

Comment: "removing" from an array is an expensive operation. There are two possibilities: Either shift all elements *after* the element to be removed one position towards the beginning (which will leave you with an empty element in the last position of the array) or create a new array with reduced size and copy all elements you want to keep to this new array.

Comment: If you are using C# and LINQ, you can still do `var newarray = existingarray.Where(x => !IsToRemove(x)).ToArray()`, which will create a new array containing all elements where (a yet to define) `IsToRemove(x)` returns `false` ...

Comment: By remove, do you mean set that index to null, or create a new array without that object? What happens if the same object is referenced by multiple indices?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I'm about creating a new array without this element.

Comment: @derpirscher I can't use linq because i can't convert type Student to T

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by this. Please show some of your code, because without that, nobody knows what's going on and nobody will be able to help you

Comment: @derpirscher I edited my question. The Physical(actually Student) class has just 2 Auto-implemented string properties

Comment: From your code and what you are trying to do, it seems you have a serious lack of knowledge about basic concepts of the object-oriented paradigm and/or generics. If you have a class with a generic type parameter (ie something like `Foo<T>` and within this class you want to do some operations based on the properties/capabilities of `T`, you must ensure, that `T` is actually restricted to types that provide that properties/capabilities ... How would you remove something from a `T[]` if you don't know whether this `T` is a `Student`, a `Vehicle` or an `Animal`

Comment: @derpirscher Yeah, I know about this. But teacher gave us this to do at home and this problem with generics is a feature of this task

Comment: @derpirscher Every type in .Net inherits an `Equals` method, so removing a item based on equality doesn't require any constraint.

Comment: `list = list.Where(x => !x.Equals(student)).ToArray();`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay yeah, but that `Equals` inherited from the `object` type provides just referential equality (`a.Equals(b)` if and only if `a == b` ie `a` and `b` are pointing to the very same location in memory) and will fail, if one tries to remove "same looking" objects (ie properties have same values but the objects are in fact different references)

Comment: This will fail if you have something like `var a = new Pyhsical{name= "baz"}; var b = new Physical({bar ="baz"}; aboba.EnrollStudent(a); aboba.RemoveStudent(b);` Eventhough `a` and `b` look exactly the same, `a.Equals(b)` will be false ...

Comment: @derpirscher That's generally what you would expect in an OO language. 2 students with the same name are still different students. If you did require value based equality, then that could be achieved using a record (data class).

Comment: @derpirscher Of course if you needed some bespoke equality comparison then you would need another approach, such as overriding `Equals` / `GetHashCode`, adding an overload that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<T>` or even a `Func<T, bool>` delegate, but the OP hasn't given any indication of that.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I have no intention of badmouthing your comment. Yeah you would expect any OO language to follow these principles. I would expect that. Anybody knowing the basics of OO would expect that. But because of how the question is asked and some of OP's comments, I've the impression, OP has very little knowledge about these principles, and so I'm not sure, they would expect that. So I just wanted to explicitly point out that possible pitfall ...

Comment: @derpirscher That's a fair comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who tried to help, but i used both hemispheres of my brain and was able to come up with a solution.
Here it is:

```
int index = Array.IndexOf(list, student);

if (index >= 0)
{
    
    for (int i = index; i < list.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        list[i] = list[i + 1];
    }

    list[list.Length - 1] = default;
    list = list.Where(x=>x!=null).ToArray();
}
```

Yeah, maybe this look like stupid, but task was just to be able deleting something from array. It's not about Optimization, etc..

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use This Code

```
List<T> genericData = new List<T>();

public RemoveData( T value )
{
 genericData.Remove (value);
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned specifically that they _"need to use Exactly Array, not a List."_.